# How to detect an AJAX called made out of JSF2.2

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

In JSF 2.0, any AJAX call made, could be checked on the XHTML page as :

```
facesContext.partialViewContext.isAjaxRequest()
```

We are attempting to migrate from JSF 2.0 to JSF 2.2.

So, On Changing the JARs to 2.2.8, the AJAX call check doesn't work.

In The `facesContext` class, i cannot find the method `isAjaxRequest()`.

Comment: And for your main initial question, did you use google? http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/PartialViewContextWrapper.html. look very good at your code and whay you describe. And look for examples in google.

Comment: It's not different. And why did you think it's in `FacesContext`? In your initial code snippet it's clearly shown that it's in `PartialViewContext`. It is still there. Please edit the question to include the code in MCVE flavor, demonstrating the actual runtime problem, so we can point out the potential mistake.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for pointing that out. It works now with facesContext.getPartialViewContext().isAjaxRequest()

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks for the link. It works now.

Comment: It should work equally fine with `#{facesContext.partialViewContext.ajaxRequest}` and with the one mentioned in your question. Your problem is caused elsewhere. A MCVE should point out that.

Comment: Hmmm, I totally missed it was used in EL and I expected some other error. Then I indeed was just lucky with posting the link